# Как прокручивать страницу до элемента при переходе? (React)

Tags: reactjs, прокрутка

Использую React-router-dom.

Нужно, что бы при переходе на страницу товара, страница прокручивалась до заголовка товара. Обычные якоря не работают в React и задание конкретного числа скролла мне не подойдёт т.к. дизайн адаптивный.

Как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: `window.scroll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
this.myRef = React.createRef(); //Создаём реф
```

Далее присваиваем реф нужному элементу

```
<div ref={this.myRef}>Элемент</div>
```

Создаём функцию прокрутки

```
this.scrollToMyRef = () => {window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.scrollHeight)
```

Вызваем через setTimeout

```
setTimeout(this.scrollToMyRef, 1000);
```

Вызывать надо именно через `setTimout`, что бы прокрутка вызвалась только когда все элементы страницы загрузились и было куда скролить.